# HTTP status code 503 throwing error #2030 in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, http, error-handling, urlloader

I'm attempting to load ads in a Flash video player then download all of the 1x1 Impression gifs linked in the VAST file. Everything works well until I hit this file:

[link to bad file](http://qlog.adap.tv/log?3a=adSuccess&51=ZX4madbHHCc_&50=ZX4madbHHCc_&72=&8=&d=&b=-2&eb=&ea=&53=&2c=&6c=&28=qUsI3M4M68M_&a8=oOt0lqLFswM_&e5=oOt0lqLFswM_&25=69352&4b=&5=89288&14=&2=&37=-2&a=&65=preroll&6a=-2&6b=-2&4f=&3=-2&c=&55=true&5c=ihighcom&5b=&18=28887&2e=vcloud.volarvideo.com%2Fapi%2Fbroadcast%2Fvmap%2F6200%3Fsite%3Dadi%26cb%3D1409758436022%2Fsite%2Fadi&2f=&30=volarvideo.com&31=&32=&90=&86=&83=&82=&af=&80=2023509566342279781&42=false&8f=&41=&21=city%3D%26county%3D%26state%3D%26zip%3D%26country%3D&1b=test&76=&77=409021133&67=&d6=57362797&bf=0&74=at&d5=1&d8=m1-44&ae=&8e=-2&e0=-2&d7=&c0=&c4=0&c5=0&92=&93=&91=ONLINE_VIDEO&45=216.54.158.178&b5=-1&33=30108&a.pub_id=&ec=&a.cv=1&rUrl=a-cv-2_10ee8_0)

This file returns status code 302 (moved temporarily) with a Location header pointing to http://httpstat.us/503 -- a very strange way of returning a 503 error

When this happens I receive an error #2030 in Flash: "End of file was encountered."

Looking at http://httpstat.us/503, the Content-Length is 23 and exactly matches the length of the returned text ("503 Service Unavailable"), so I don't believe it's a problem with the server response.

In my Flash file I have bound listeners to both SecurityError and IOError events:

```
    loader.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, onOpen);
    loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, onStatus);
    loader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
    loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);

    loader.load(request);
```

So my question is: What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to detect and handle status code 503 in Flash?

Comment: I have standard _Error #2032: Stream Error._ for that url

Comment: @fsbmain That's bizarre... I have a global uncaught error handler which simply logs the time and the error ID, and it posts "12:08:29 PM -- CRASH DETECTED -- Error: #2030". The stack trace is just two lines: "flash.net.URLLoader.onComplete" followed by "flash.net.URLStream.readBytes"

Comment: @fsbmain I just did some more tests and found that when I open the SWF locally (file://C:\...) I get error #2032. It's when I open it online (http://...) that I get error #2030. So it may be Flash Sandbox related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting with this I found it's a bug in Flash Player -- when you receive a 302 the Flash Player secretly spins up a new URLLoader to handle the second request, but maps all of the events and function calls. Because it is a separate object, any errors that are thrown will not be caught.

My solution was to add a global, static counter for 503 errors then have an uncaught error handler.

1. Receive a 503 error, increment the counter
2. Receive an uncaught error, check counter:

   - If error ID is 2030 AND counter > 0, decrement counter
   - Else, throw the error